# Laravel RedirectResponse with() method not working

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have a registration form which after pressing 'submit' button shows some messages - if passed password is too short or if registration is successful. For errors I use `withErrors()` method, which works correctly. When I'm trying to pass other variable to session using either

```
return Redirect::to('login')->with('success', [/**/])
```

or

```
return Redirect::to('login')->withSuccess([/**/])
```

variables in my view seem unset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass messages with session you can follow this:

In Controller:

```
Session::flash('message', 'error message here......');
```

In view:

```
{{Session::get("message")}}
```

This one show the error message .Try this.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can set success message in session like this in controller..

```
\Session::flash('flash_message', 'registration is successful.');
return redirect("/successPage");
```

and show error message in view like this..

```
{{ Session::get('flash_message')}}
```